# INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition - Jest jsdom firebase emulator testing

Tags: angular, firebase, jestjs

Hi I'm trying to get client side firebase auth with emulator testing to work in jest using Angular. I *need* to use [`firebase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) in a `jsdom` environment since I want to use `firebase-admin` together in my spec files to do any test/emulator cleanup work. This line causes the following error:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat'
firebase.client.auth() <--- `INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition`
```

Anyone know how to get around this issue?

Config for reference:

```
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'jest-test',
    preset: '../../../../jest.preset.js',
    globals: {
      'ts-jest': {
        tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.e2e.spec.json',
      },
    },
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.[tj]s$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/../jest.setup.ts'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'html'],
    coverageDirectory: '../../../../coverage/somewhere',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom', <---
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same problem. Did you resolve it?